# Cauchy integral formula for a point outside the simple closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, analytic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

Show that if $f$ is analytic inside and on a simple closed curve $C$ and $z_0$ not in $C$ then
$$ (n-1)!\int_C \frac{f^{(m)}(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}dz=(m+n-1)!\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{m+n}}dz$$

Since it is stated that $z_0$ is not in $C$, I believe we have to prove the statement for points both inside and outside the simple closed curve. For a point inside the curve I know the answer. We only need to evaluate the value of the $(m+n-1)th$ derivative of $f(z)$ and $(n-1)th $ derivative of $f^{(m)}(z)$ at $z_0$ using Cauchy's integral formula and equate them. But how do I prove the same for apoint outside the simple closed curve ?

Comment: If it's outside, both sides of the equation are 0.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Can you please explain how ?

Comment: The integrands are both analytic on a simply connected domain in which the curve is included.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I get it now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just Cauchy's theorem.   When there's no singularity within the contour, the integrand is holomorphic, and the theorem says that the integral is zero.